# Does a child element receive the characteristics of a parent element?

Tags: html, css

**This css code has a form in a div and i do not know why if you remove the form-container as a class the form will not be like a list again.**

```
.form-container form{
    background:#fff;
    flex-direction:column;
    display:flex;


  }
```

Comment: you might have another style for form. Try body form{}

Comment: Why would a form be "like a list again"? Forms aren't list-like in the first place.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Provide a clear and detailed description of the expected and observed behaviour. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: I struggled in putting the code in so i could not put an example and this was the little i could put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `.form-container` targets every `form` within the div you are applying the style to. If you remove it, and will leave it like `.form`, it wont do anything, because dot before text is class selector, and since you probably dont have `class="form"` on your form, it wont do anything.

Therefore, if you want it to work, remove the dot. But keep in mind that then this CSS will effect every form within your whole page.